# Geometric datatype that's smaller than 32bytes in PostGis?

Tags: postgis-2.0

I'm putting together a database that will contain many billions of points and multipoints and the 32byte size of the default data type (SRID=0) is starting to be a real headache for me.  Is there another SRID that stores positive integer data in a smaller size?  I'd be very happy with an unsigned 16bit integer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostGIS geometry format stores the coordinates as 64bit double precission. Not 32 bit. Depending on your use case it might be of interest to encode data as twkb with st_astwkb function. Then you can store it as bytea. Then you have to translate it back when you want to use it in a postgis function with st_geomfromtwkb.

Twkb compresses by storing delta values between two points and encoding it with varInt the same way as in protobuffer.

Comment: _This_ is exactly what I was looking for!